# Find Function Scope of Position in Python Source Code

Tags: python, function, scope, ctags

## Background

- I'm creating a Most Recently Used Function Browser plugin for Vim.
- I need to **find the name of the current function the cursor is in.**
- For other languages I could search for "{ }" enclosures, but python uses whitespace/tabs.

## Example

#### Assume I have these functions in foo.py...

```
def foo(file):
    fileLines = []
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            fileLines.append(line)

    def nested_function():
        pass

    # FILE POSITION
    for line in fileLines:
        print line
```

#### I want to write a function that returns the name of the function of a position ("FILE POSITION" in the example)

```
def get_function_scope(sourceFile, lineNumber, columnNumber):
    pass
```

#### So for the above example I want something like...

```
fxnName = get_function_scope("foo.py", lineNumber=9, columnNumber=4)
print fxnName
# "foo"
```

---

## Approaches

- Exuberant CTags gives me a nice list of all function/class/method locations but not the line numbers of the scope each function occupies.
- Not sure if inspect can help even if code isn't "live"?
- I'm thinking of working backwards from the indents until I reach a function/method definition.

#### Is there is a standard way of doing this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: One question: When this `get_function_scope` is performed, is it guaranteed that the code will parse (that it won't raise a SyntaxError?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson No I suppose not - the code is currently being edited so it's not guaranteed to be valid Python code.

Comment: I did something similar to this using `ast`. Keep meaning to tidy it up and publish it.

Comment: @TomDignan I understand that it won't always be possible to get a correct function, but will using ast work on code with SyntaxErrors like David Robinson mentioned?

Comment: The indents method seems reasonable, but then how do you deal with newlines/comments, which won't match the current indent level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I came up with:

https://gist.github.com/cgreer/7366297